# Why we have a stack overflow in a recursive function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack, overflow

where do i have an endless loop?

```
 f2 :: Int->Int->Int
 f2 n d 
    | d==2
       = 0 
    | n `mod` d ==0  && n`mod` d^3==0
       = 1 + (f2 n d-1)
    | otherwise
       = 0 + (f2 n d-1)
```

Comment: What values did you call the function with?

Comment: And what actually happened? Your title says stack overflow, but your actual question mentions an endless loop (presumably a non-responses program). These are different things and have different causes.

Comment: it shows C-stack overflow , so i guess the problem is in recursion

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need the `n \`mod\` d == 0` check. If something's divisible by `d^3` then it's automatically divisible by `d`

Comment: Stack overflows in Haskell are not caused by recursion itself, as they are in imperative languages. Haskell stack overflows are due to too much laziness.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Robin,but it shows the same error again.

Answer (score 9):

This is a precedence issue. `(f2 n d-1)` is parsed as `(f2 n d) - 1`, which leads to infinite recursion because `f2` is calling itself with the same arguments. You want `f2 n (d - 1)` instead.